# Рекомендации на сайте

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Как делают рекомендации на сайтах, например Ютуб

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариантов много, от банального подсовывания просто хороших материалов из популярных, для этого пользователя, категорий(или просто популярных материалов этой категории), до магии с использованием теории вероятности.
В [этой](http://habrahabr.ru/post/84364/) статье достаточно подробно написано, как сделать и как работает Байесовская экспертная система(в Я.Маркете используется именно она). Её применение, для меня, самое естественное.

Comment: @Алексей Лобанов в какой статье ?

Comment: @Zow, http://habrahabr.ru/post/84364/

Answer (score 0):

Если это вопрос, хотя знака вопросительного не увидел, то вот вам ответ :

Всё видео на youtub'e разобрано по категориям, каждое видео содержит огромное количество информации о себе, например метки и канал, описание и название. Сервис ищет видео например на том же канале, из того же раздела, что и видео, которое вы посмотрели недавно, ищет похожие.